# MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync(..) does not return in WP 8.1

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

I'm using Azure Mobile Services login service, it's working as expected on Windows 8.1 but on WP 8.1 it shows the service login page (Microsoft, Google, etc.) I put in my credentials and then it returns to the app (does not show the consent).
No exception, nothing. It looks like the thread is frozen and control is returned to the UI thread.
In Windows 8.1 it enters foo(), bar(), or fooBar() but in WP nothing happens after LoginAsync in my code.

```
    public RelayCommand<String> LoginCommand {
        get { return _loginCommand ?? (_loginCommand = new RelayCommand<String>(Login)); }
    }

    private async void Login(string provider)
    {
        try
        {
            var u = await AzureClient.LoginAsync(provider);
            foo();
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException iop)
        {
            //user canceled 
            bar();
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fooBar()
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: How are you calling this method? Are you using `Task.Wait` perhaps?

Comment: I updated the code with method definition. I'm using MVVMLight RelayCommand. It's getting called from the main thread in the view creating a worker thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Phone 8.1 Login uses the Windows Auth Broker behind the scenes and requires an additional call in order for login to complete (due to support of lower memory devices)

What you need is to also call the LoginComplete() function in the OnActivated method as shown in this tutorial for Windows Universal Apps:

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-windows-universal-dotnet-get-started-users/

Answer (score 0):

If you find that LoginComplete doesn't exist
because it's just an extension